# Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

I would like to know if I can install IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 and NOT Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: This should be moved to ServerFault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short version: No, you cannot.

The IIS version has always been tied to the OS, there are many underlying things in the OS to support it.  Keep in mind that 2008 R2 will run 32-bit programs including web applications via [WoW64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) if that's your aversion to upgrading to R2.

Comment: Not entirely true... IIS version ties started with Windows 2000, but NT4 could run multiple versions of IIS... after NT5/win2k they were bound together, mainly to encourage system upgrades with IIS.

Comment: @Tracker1 - The above is still true, the version has always been tied to the OS...you are limited in what IIS level you can run on *any* version of windows including NT4.  For example NT4 cannot run anything above IIS 4.0 (and even the selection there was limited by which service pack you were on). It started being a 1:1 tie after NT4, but that's more specific than I was above. I'd imagine for 99.99% of people this isn't an issue though, since something running via IIS on the client version of NT4 must be *extremely* rare at this point.

Comment: I totally agree, it's a non-issue today, and was more complicated in the NT 3.5-4 era... was just adding some depth.  Personally, I wish MS would separate IIS back out again, but the versioning pushes sales these days.  Where I'm really surprised is that nobody has done a good job of an out-of-the-box Mono setup for Linux.  I've found that quite a few .Net projects run without issue, though I think Windows Server Web Edition (being displaced with 8/2012) was a good enough value to not be needed.